# Finding MIN Invoice Number Per Customer and Removing All Rows That Don't Match

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have an Excel file that shows online sales data. There are multiple columns, as you would expect, two of which are Customer ID and Invoice Number.

My aim is to only keep rows where the Invoice Number is the first (or MIN) Invoice Number for each Customer.

On a duplicate tab, we want the same thing, but only for the second Invoice Number per Customer (i.e. the second purchase).

On a side note, there can be multiple rows for the same Customer ID and same Invoice Number because the rows are at Item level, so it may look like this:

```
Row 1: Customer ID = 24; Invoice Number = 1014; Item = Jelly Beans
Row 2: Customer ID = 24; Invoice Number = 1014; Item = Candy Bars
```

So, that's okay. We just want to make sure any rows where the Customer's Invoice Number does not reflect their first purchase (or second purchase, in the second instance) is removed from the spreadsheet.

Is there a VBA (or even just functions) to achieve this? Even in steps: such as first highlighting those rows and then using another VBA to delete rows that are highlighted?

Again, in a nutshell I'm looking to only keep rows with the MIN(Invoice Number) per Customer ID.

Comment: Yes, of course there is '*a VBA (or even just functions) to achieve this*'. What a silly question! Hire a programmer and he/she will tell you the same thing.

Comment: A bit of an uncalled for response there, @Jeeped, as asking questions is after all the purpose of the forum.

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIFS to count the number of times the customer number has appeared. Use a reference that is anchored to the first cell and changes as you drag down.

Assuming your customer numbers are in column A, insert this into B1 and copy down:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A1)
```

Filter on 1 or 2 accordingly.

**Edit:**

I didn't realise that you only wanted the first row. You can exploit the fact that MATCH will return the first result and check if it equals the row number:

```
=MATCH(A1,A:A,0)=ROW(A1)
```

Note that you may need to offset `MATCH` slightly if your data doesn't start from row 1. For example, if your data starts in row 3, you will need to offset your `MATCH` result by 2:

```
=MATCH(A1,A:A,0)+2=ROW(A1)
```

Now you can filter on the first column equalling 1 or 2 and the second column equalling `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan - it's still proving difficult to complete the end result of returning only first invoices per customer though. Have moved the data to MySQL for better manipulation.